# Upload File to Firebase Ddmin SDK (GCS) with https stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

When trying to upload a stream into a Google bucket I am getting `Error: Not Found` when using get method and `Error: socket hang up` after a few second delay when using the request method.

Everything with firebase seems to be initialized fine, and when I log the stream I see the data coming through, but what would be the best way to write a file to GCS using a remote URL?

```
const storage = firebase.storage()

const bucket = storage.bucket("bucket/path")
const file = bucket.file("filename.pdf")

const url =
  "https://url/to/file/filename.pdf"


https.get(url, async (res) => {
  console.log(res)
  res.pipe(file.createWriteStream())
})
```

Comment: `storage.bucket("bucket/path")` : buckets do not have a (directory) path. The path is part of the object name.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks, that was the issue. Moving the folder path into the file fixed it

Comment: Post an answer with your solution so that the question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the issue was passing the folder path into the bucket name instead of the file name.

Bucket name is available in the storage console, and do not pass in a folder path.

Bucket name example:
`gs://bucket.appspot.com`
(remove the gs:// when passing it as a value)

```
const bucket = storage.bucket("bucketname")
const file = bucket.file("bucket/path/filename.pdf")
```